# How to play MMS stream with VLC via command-line?

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, vlc-media-player

I try to wake up in the morning with VLC and Cron (Mac OS X).

the command Cron should run is :

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC mms://213.8.138.13/glz-stream
```

but VLC gives me the following output:

```
[0x100202b88] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x114740818] access_mms access error: error while asking for file -1
[0x114740818] access_mms access error: error while asking for file -1
[0x114740818] access_mms access error: cannot connect to server
[0x114740818] access_mms access error: error: HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
[0x101e681a8] main input error: open of `mms://213.8.138.13/glz-stream' failed: (null)`
```

All it does is to add the stream to the playlist – I want to play it immediately (because i wanna get up...)

If i'm trying to play the  `mms://213.8.138.13/glz-stream` via the GUI, it plays it without any problems.

I also tried the following commands:

```
open -a "VLC" mms://213.8.138.13/glz-stream<br>
Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --open  mms://213.8.138.13/glz-stream<br>
Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC --play-and-stop  mms://213.8.138.13/glz-stream
```

None of them work, they just add the stream to the playlist.

So how do I play a MMS stream via Mac OS terminal in VLC?

Comment: Not as an answer to the VLC question, but to help people who look for an up-to-date live stream info for גלי צהל: as of Feb. 2014, the link is http://50.22.219.97:14959/;?1392189709172.mp3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following, the `-I rc` is what tells it to run without a GUI:

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -I rc mms://wm-live.world.mii-streaming.net/live/klove/high_01
```